# PnP Site Provisioning saving site template, but not homepage

Tags: pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

I am using PnP PowerShell to save a SharePoint TeamSite (STO#3) as a provisioning template.  This works fine.  However, the homepage of the site is not being saved.
My PowerShell Script:

```
# Variables definition
$tenant = "apptivsolutionscom";
$sourceSite = "/PnPTestHome";
$templateFile = "C:\PnPDropDirectory\PnPTemplate.xml";

# Office 365 Login 
$webUrl = "https://{0}.sharepoint.com{1}/" -f $tenant, $sourceSite;
Write-Output $("Connecting to {0}" -f $webUrl);
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $webUrl -Credentials WCMStoredCredentials;
#use the line bellow to connect if you are using multi factor authentication  
#Connect-PnPOnline -Url $webUrl -UseWebLogin;

# Save Template
Write-Output "Saving PnP template";
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out $templateFile -PersistBrandingFiles -PersistPublishingFiles;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a classic site? Where is the home page located? Site Pages, Site Assets?
Try adding these to the parameters.

```
 -IncludeNativePublishingFiles -Handlers All
```